# Killed at button press

Tags: android, button, android-intent, listener

I've been reading and looking into a few tutorials, such as
[this](http://manisivapuram.blogspot.com/2011/06/how-to-use-startactivityforresult.html)

And yet I still have problems of my app shutting down. So I'm guessing it has something do with the button interaction part, but I'm not sure how to solve it. (Gaemscreen1.class is my next activity)
I'm new to Android, and I barely managed to open my test app. The problem comes when I press a button, expecting to go another scene, but ended up with a forced shut down.

Here's my test code:

```
package com.example.testandy04;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Title extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_title);//set layout class
        init();
    }

    public void init(){
         Button start = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonT1);

         start.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){                 
             public void onClick(View vv){                   
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
                 Intent intent = new Intent(Title.this, Gaemscreen1.class);
                 startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
             }
         });     
    }
}
```

Any ideas, anyone?

Comment: is R.id.buttonT1 declared inside R.layout.activity_title?

Comment: clearly you didnt declare your another activity in manifest file. Refer to the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Have you declared your `Gaemscreen1` Activity in `AndroidManifest.xml`?

```
<manifest ... >
  <application ... >
      <activity android:name=".ExampleActivity" />
      ...
  </application ... >
  ...
</manifest >
```

Please check the official [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html).
Other possible problem is that you have no `buttonT1` placed in your `activity_title` layout xml.